# How to create a WP Capability that limits editing to posts in a certain category?

Tags: capabilities

Is there a way to create a WP User Capability that only allows editing of posts in a certain category and no other posts?

There are plugins that do this, but wondering how to do it in PHP code. It seems to be outside of the abilities of native WP functions.